# Comparing user input unicode strings in Python 2.7

Tags: python, unicode, string-comparison

What is the best way to compare a string entered by the user with another string?

For example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals

user_input = raw_input("Please, write árido: ").decode("utf8")
if u"árido" == user_input:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "FALSE"
```

EDIT:

This

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from unicodedata import normalize
import sys

uinput2 = "árbol"
uinput = raw_input("type árbol: ")

print "Encoding %s" % sys.stdout.encoding
print "User Input \t\tProgram Input"
print "-"*50
print "%s \t\t\t%s \t(raw value)" % (uinput, uinput2)
print "%s \t\t\t%s \t(unicode(value))" % (unicode(uinput), unicode(uinput2))
print "%s \t\t\t%s \t(value.decode('utf8'))" % (uinput.decode("utf-8"), uinput2.decode("utf-8"))
print "%s \t\t\t%s \t(normalize('NFC',value))" % (normalize("NFC",uinput.decode("utf-8")), normalize("NFC",uinput2.decode("utf-8")));
print "\n\nUser Input \t\tProgram Input (Repr)"
print "-"*50
print "%s \t%s" % (repr(uinput),repr(uinput2))
print "%s \t%s \t(unicode(value))" % (repr(unicode(uinput)), repr(uinput2))
print "%s \t%s \t(value.decode('utf8'))" % (repr(uinput.decode("utf-8")), repr(uinput2.decode("utf-8")))
print "%s \t%s \t(normalize('NFC',value)))" % (repr(normalize("NFC",uinput.decode("utf-8"))), repr(normalize("NFC",uinput2.decode("utf-8"))));
```

prints:

```
type árbol: árbol
Encoding utf-8
User Input      Program Input
--------------------------------------------------
Ã¡rbol          árbol   (raw value)
Ã¡rbol          árbol   (unicode(value))
Ã¡rbol          árbol   (value.decode('utf8'))
Ã¡rbol          árbol   (normalize('NFC',value))


User Input              Program Input (Repr)
--------------------------------------------------
'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1rbol'  u'\xe1rbol'
u'\xc3\xa1rbol'         u'\xe1rbol'     (unicode(value))
u'\xc3\xa1rbol'         u'\xe1rbol'     (value.decode('utf8'))
u'\xc3\xa1rbol'         u'\xe1rbol'     (normalize('NFC',value)))
```

Any idea? I haven't problems when I work with other languages ​​like Java. This only happens to me with python. I'm using Eclipse.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Best way? What are the problems with your way, and what do you want to improve?

Comment: The comparison always returns false :(

Comment: Please include the output of `print repr(u"árido")` and `print repr(user_input)`.

Comment: u'\xe1rido' and
'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1rido'

Comment: I would definitely expect `user_input` to be a Unicode string if you have done `decode("utf8")` on the `raw_input`, is this from using the `raw_input` result without the decode?

Comment: Is there *any* chance that there is a typo in your actual code and it is using `encode("utf8")` instead of `decode`?  `'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1rido'` looks a lot like doubly encoded utf-8.

Comment: It looks like your input is encoded as utf-8 *twice*: `u'\xe1'.encode("utf8").decode("latin1").encode("utf-8") == b'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1'`

Comment: `inp = raw_input("Please, write árido: ")
    print repr(inp)
    print repr("árido")` 
is

Please, write árido: árido
'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1rido'
u'\xe1rido'

Comment: What happens if you run it in a terminal instead of Eclipse? How do you input `á` character? Do you use copy-paste?

Comment: I tried it in a terminal and something similar happens. The repr() function returns different results between the variable read with raw_input() and the variable that has been written in the code (using unicode text). I haven´t used copy / paste (nowhere).

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the character encoding of your terminal,

> > import sys
> >
> > sys.stdin.encoding

If it is UTF-8, then decode should be fine. Otherwise, you have to decode the raw_input with right encoding.

like, raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding) to check whether it is proper along with Unicode Normalization, if needed.

Comment: `print sys.stdin.encoding` prints **utf-8**

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach isn't bad, but you should probably use [`unicodedata.normalize()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) for the comparison.  The docs linked above explain why this is a good idea.  For example, try evaluating the following:

```
u'Ç' == u'Ç'
```

Spoiler alert, this will give you `False` because the left side is the sequence U+0043 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C) U+0327 (COMBINING CEDILLA), and the right side is the single character U+00C7 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA).

You can use `unicodedata.normalize()` to handle this properly by first converting the strings to a normalized form.  For example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unicodedata import normalize

from __future__ import unicode_literals

user_input = normalize('NFC', raw_input("Please, write árido: ").decode("utf8"))
if normalize('NFC', u"árido") == user_input:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "FALSE"
```

Comment: this does not work

`user_input = normalize('NFC',raw_input("Please, write árido: ").decode("utf8"))
if normalize('NFC', u"árido") == user_input:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "FALSE"`